# Length of Spiral in a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Problem**
Take a positive constant real number $c$. Draw a rough sketch and find the length of the spiral in the plane given by $(x(t),y(t))=(e^{-ct}\cos(t),e^{-ct}\sin(t))$ for $0\leq t<\infty$.

**Attempt**
Have never seen a question like this come up before so I have no idea how to approach it. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you been introduced to arc length of functions?

Comment: Yes but I haven't seen a question asked like this so I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: There is a standard formula for the length of the arc in parametric form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be clear that $x'(t) = \frac{dx}{dt}$ represents incremental changes in $x$ as a function of $t$, and a similar definition for $y'(t)$.
This being the case, you can consider an incremental change in location on the plane as $$\sqrt{\left(x'(t)\right)^2 + \left(y'(t)\right)^2}$$
and the problem reduces to integrating this through the relevant values of $t$.
To start, 
$$x'(t) = -e^{-ct}\left(c\cos(t) + \sin(t)\right)$$
$$y'(t) = e^{-ct}\left(\cos(t) - c\sin(t)\right)$$
Then we can brute force through the integral, using $\sin^2(t) + \cos^2(t) = 1$ to help eliminate terms.
$$L = \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\left(x'(t)\right)^2 + \left(y'(t)\right)^2}\ dt$$
$$ = \int_0^\infty e^{-ct}\sqrt{\left(c\cos(t) + \sin(t)\right)^2 + \left(\cos(t) - c\sin(t)\right)^2}\ dt$$$$
= \int_0^\infty e^{-ct}\sqrt{1 + c^2}\ dt = \sqrt{1 + \frac1{c^2}}$$

Edit:
Considering $y(t) = e^{-ct}\sin(t)$, we can let $f(t) = e^{-ct}$, $g(t) = \sin(t)$.
Then $f'(t) = -ce^{-ct}$, $g'(t) = \cos(t)$. From the product rule, we know that $$y'(t) = \left(f(t)g(t)\right)' = f'(t)g(t) + f(t)g'(t)$$
Adding this all together we get:
$$y'(t) = -ce^{-ct}\sin(t) + e^{-ct}\cos(t) = e^{-ct}\left(\cos(t) - c\sin(t)\right)$$

Comment: Surely you mean $y'(t)$ on the second line after "To start,".

Comment: Thanks, I was using the copy/paste functionality a little to rapidly there

Comment: I figured you were. We all do and sometimes it bites us back. :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I'm confused about how you get $x^{\prime}(t)$ and $y^{\prime}(t)$. I understand you differentiate but my answers are $x^{\prime}(t)=-e^{-ct}sint$ and $y^{\prime}(t)=e^{-ct}cost$

Comment: @teme92, Don't forget the product rule:
$$\left(f(t)\cdot g(t)\right)' = f'(t)g(t) + f(t)g'(t)$$

Comment: Oh sorry so $x{\prime}(t)=ce^{-ct}sint$ and $y{\prime}(t)=-ce^{-ct}cost$

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'll make an edit to the post

Comment: I don't know how I didn't realise that's what you were trying to say. Tiredness is getting to me I think. Thanks a million for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

Think of this problem in terms of taking a small piece $ds$ of the curve $s$.  Ultimately we want to integrate this and find $\int ds$ which will give us the arclength.  Notice that if $v$ is our speed (distinct from velocity) we can rewrite $ds = vdt$, hence our integral becomes $\int vdt$.  The speed as a function of time is the magnitude of the velocity vector at each point which we can write as $\textbf{v} = (\dot{x}(t), \dot{y}(t))$.  We then obtain our velocity

$$
\textbf{v}(t) \;\; = \;\; (-ce^{-ct}\cos t - e^{-ct}\sin t, -ce^{-ct}\sin t + e^{-ct} \cos t).
$$

The speed $v = ||\textbf{v}||$ and is given by

\begin{eqnarray*}
v^2 & = & c^2e^{-2ct} \cos^2t + 2ce^{-2ct}\sin t \cos t + e^{-2ct} \sin^2t \\
&& + c^2e^{-2ct}\sin^2t - 2ce^{-2ct}\sin t \cos t + e^{-2ct}\cos^2t \\
& = & c^2e^{-2ct} + e^{-2ct}
\end{eqnarray*}

and thus $v = \sqrt{(c^2 + 1)e^{-2ct}} = e^{-ct}\sqrt{c^2+1}$.  Your equation for arclength reduces to

$$
\int_0^\infty \sqrt{c^2+1} e^{-ct} dt \;\; =\;\; \frac{\sqrt{c^2+1}}{c}.
$$

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. This seems like a long way round compared to other methods but thanks for the help.

Comment: @teme92 Glad to help.  I was trying to provide some context for why the equation works the way it does.  In general if $\textbf{v}$ is the velocity vector, you just compute $\int ||\textbf{v}(t)||dt$ to get the arclength.

Answer (score 2):

> Given a parameterisation $\mathbf{r}:\left[a,b\right]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ of a curve $\mathcal{C}$, the length of $\mathcal{C}$ is given by $$\int_{a}^{b} \ \left\| \dfrac{\text{d}\mathbf{r}}{\text{d}t}(t) \right\| \text{ d}t$$

In your case, $\mathbf{r}(t) = \left( e^{-ct}\cos(t), e^{-ct}\sin(t) \right)$ is the parameterisation of your spiral where $t \in \left[0, +\infty \right)$.

> It'd be more meaningful to express your integral as $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{n} \left\| \mathbf{r}'(t) \right\| \text{ d}t $$

Answer (score 2):

By observation, the curve laid out by the equation is a spiral starting at (1, 0) and going counter-clockwise and approaching the origin. Note that the curve is given in parametric form and in cartesian coordinates. Using the arc length formula, the resulting integration would require a lot of work.

This problem is best solved by converting from a cartesian coordinate system into polar coordinates. Also note that the common term in both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ is $e^{-ct}$. Let's factor it out.

(EDIT: This is not true. It is not necessary to convert into polar coordinates. Do it anyways, it is good practice and a course in multivariate calculus most certainly will give you more than a few problems forcing you to do coordinate conversions.)

$\vec{r}(t)=e^{-ct}[cos(t),sin(t)]$

Now, let's convert the vector into polar coordinates. By the pythagorean theorem.

$r(\theta)=e^{-c\,\theta}$

Since the spiral is just a unit circle scaled by the exponential function. Now we have the curve in polar coordinates, and we can use the nifty arc length formula for polar coordinates.

$L=\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{r(\theta)^2+r'(\theta)^2} d\theta$

For your problem, this results in the integral.

$L(c)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{e^{-2c\,\theta}+c^2e^{-2c\,\theta}} d\theta$

$L(c)=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-c\,\theta}\cdot\sqrt{1+c^2} d\theta$

$L(c)=\sqrt{1+c^2}\cdot\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-c\,\theta} d\theta$

$L(c)=\frac{\sqrt{1+c^2}}{c}$

Now plug in any value for c, and you'll get your arc length.